# Make ListView Item select and click automatically with button click

Tags: android, listview, select, buttonclick

I would like to know how do I select the listview first item select and click automatically with a button click.

With this below code I'm able to select the first row but not able to select.

```
lv1.setItemChecked(0, true);
```

This is my listview click event :

```
final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

// Pass results to ListViewAdapter Class
adapter = new ItemListBaseAdapter(this, somedata);
// Binds the Adapter to the ListView
lv1.setAdapter(adapter);
lv1.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE); 

lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
        //btnNxt.setEnabled(true);
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FirstActivity.class);
        // Pass all data 
        i.putExtra("mydata", somedata);
        // Pass a single position
        i.putExtra("position", position);
        // Open SingleItemView.java Activity
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated !
And please do let me know if any one want any more info regarding this so that I'll update my question.

Comment: Just try it by set setChoiceMode to listview before initializing the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

selecting the item is not the same as clicking the item.
If you want to react to a selection of an item use the `setOnItemSelectedListener` but if you want to react to the user clicking one, use `setOnItemClickListener`.

Comment: I think thats what I have used.But my question is how to get the selected item on button click.

Comment: I thought you wanted when the button is clicked: "Select the first item and fire the event".  but what you really want is to know what the currently selected value is?

Comment: @Raghunandan-No I dot have any buttons..do you want me to post my XML ?

Comment: @jkhouw1-Actually when I manually click the listview item it works fine.Initially my selection is empty. So I have thought of making the first row checked automatically when the activity loads. And when I click the button I need to capture the selected row and move it to the next activity.

Comment: in the setOnItemClickListener, set a tag (perhaps the tag of the button) to the value that was clicked.  Then when you click the button, retrieve the value of the tag.

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
 lv1.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

Use a `SparseBooleanArray` to get checked items

Example:

To check the first row `myList.setItemChecked(0, true)`.

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView myList;
    Button getChoice;
    String[] listContent = {"January","February","March","April","May","June", "July","August","September","October","November","December" };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        getChoice = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,listContent);
        myList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        myList.setAdapter(adapter);
        getChoice.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
                String selected = "";
                int cntChoice = myList.getCount();
                SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray = myList.getCheckedItemPositions();
                for(int i = 0; i < cntChoice; i++){
                    if(sparseBooleanArray.get(i)) {
                        selected += myList.getItemAtPosition(i).toString() + "\n";

                    }
                }

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, selected,  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }});
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
         >

    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Snap

[image]

Comment: @Raghunandan-Its not the issue of selecting single or multiple. But I need to get the initally set row ie..lv1.setItemChecked(0, true); which makes checked the first row but its position is null.

Comment: @coder check the edit and sap shot. i checked 3  rows and the 3 row items are displayed in toast

Answer (score 0):

Try it by set setChoiceMode to listview before initializing the adapter.

```
lv1.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE); 

adapter = new ItemListBaseAdapter(this, somedata);

lv1.setAdapter(adapter);
```